# AngularJS Custom Filter to filter type of items

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to write a filter so that it filters me type of items.. for instance, there will be some dropdown item like `rich`, `poor`, `very poor`, in HTML/frontend... when i click on `rich` it should filter rich type of filter in `ng-repeat`

here you go for my object:

```
$scope.names = [
    {name:'Jani',country:'Norway', type: 'RICH'},
    {name:'Carl',country:'Sweden', type: 'POOR'},
    {name:'Margareth',country:'England', type: 'EXTREM POOR'},
    {name:'Hege',country:'Norway', type: 'RICH'},
    {name:'Joe',country:'Denmark', type: 'VERY POOR'},
    {name:'Gustav',country:'Sweden', type: 'VERY POOR'},
    {name:'Birgit',country:'Denmark', type: 'VERY RICH'},
    {name:'Mary',country:'England', type: 'RICH'},
    {name:'Kai',country:'Norway', type: 'POOR'}
    ];
```

the filter i am crafting:

```
app.filter('typeFilter', function() {
    return function(x) {

        return #;
    };
});
```

but I failed to do it... can anyone help me to craft it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in filter 'filter':

In your html, use this:

```
Enter your type here:
<input ng-model="type"/>
<div ng-repeat="item in names | filter: type">
  {{item.name}} - {{item.type}}
</div>
```

You can more with this filter, for reference:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Edit #01

You can also use a function with the filter:

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="item in names | filter: myFilter">
  {{item.name}} - {{item.type}}
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.myFilter = function(item){
  if (item.type === something){
    return item;
  }
}
```

This way you can filter with multiple properties, etc

Comment: Yes, i know i can craft it with a built-in filter but i don't want it with built.. I want custom for a reason...

Comment: Also, your given solution if there is only Colum... but if there is multiple column, it will not works

Comment: Well, you didn't specify... what is the reason? You can also use a function in the built-in filter, which would be very similar to a custom filter

Comment: The reason is simple, I am learning how it works, that is why I ignore built-in filter... also, know that, you cant do many thing with buit in filter